# Entering Text in horizontal form

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a horizontal form with an upload button, like the source code below.  I’m trying to use selenium to input the ‘newRes’ file path below into the horizontal box.  I’ve tried all the lines of code below.  I’ve commented out each failed attempt.  They all throw errors related to not being able to find the element.  I’m new to selenium, could someone please let me know what part of the source code I should be looking for below and any tips on how to input the ‘newRes’ file path in the box that currently shows ‘oldFile.docx’, would greatly be appreciated.

code:

```
newRes='/Users/new_file.docx'

# upload_element = driver.find_element_by_link_text(“oldFile.docx")
# upload_element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Upload")
# upload_element = driver.find_element_by_id('resume')
# upload_element = driver.find_element_by_id('resumeUpload')
upload_element.send_keys(newRes)#+keys.Keys.ENTER)


# assert 'Resume' in driver.page_source
# action = action_chains.ActionChains(driver)

# action.send_keys(newRes)
# action.perform()
```

source code:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback" data-ng-switch="isOnEditMode" data-ng-class="{'has-success': (profile.resume.fileName &amp;&amp; frmInputResume.resumeFile.$error.diceFileFormat==false &amp;&amp; frmInputResume.resumeFile.$error.diceMaxFileUploadSize==false), 'has-error': (!profile.resume.fileName || frmInputResume.resumeFile.$error.diceFileFormat == true || frmInputResume.resumeFile.$error.diceMaxFileUploadSize == true)}">
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: true --><div data-ng-switch-when="true" class="ng-scope">
                <label class="col-md-3 profile-summary-label">Résumé:</label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-7 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="resumeUpload" class="file-input-btn btn-block">
                        <input type="file" name="resumeFile" id="resumeFileInput" data-dice-file-input-reader="" data-file-model="resume" data-ng-model="resumeInput" data-supported-file-extension-pattern="diceRegex.supportedFileExtensions" data-max-file-upload-size="2048000" data-file-read-callback="uploadResume(resume)" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <span class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-file-name ng-binding" data-ng-class="{'text-muted': !profile.resume.fileName}">old_file.docx</span>
                        <span class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-file-choose">Upload</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" style="line-height:46px; height:46px; width:46px;" data-ng-class="{'icon-filled-check-4': (profile.resume.fileName &amp;&amp; frmInputResume.resumeFile.$error.diceFileFormat == false &amp;&amp; frmInputResume.resumeFile.$error.diceMaxFileUploadSize==false), 'icon-filled-delete-2': (!profile.resume.fileName || frmInputResume.resumeFile.$error.diceFileFormat==true || frmInputResume.resumeFile.$error.diceMaxFileUploadSize == true)}"></span>
                    <span class="error ng-hide" ng-show="frmInputResume.resumeFile.$error.diceFileFormat" style="color: #C00;">We support .doc, .docx, .pdf, .txt, .rtf, up to 2MB.</span
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below code.This will upload the file you would like.

```
file_upload = driver.find_element_by_id("resumeFileInput")
file_upload.send_keys(/path/to/file) # Like "C:\user\desktop\test1.txt"
```

Please let me know if this work for you.